# Are hardware-related inquiries strictly prohibited on Server Fault, belonging instead on Super User?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just asked a question on Server Fault.  After consulting the about page, to ensure I am choosing the correct place for the question I decided on server fault OVER super user.

This is a quote from the Server Fault about page:

> No matter what types of servers or
>   desktops you administer, or what
>   operating systems you happen to call
>   home -- getting better at what we do,
>   together, is our goal.

So I got comments and got marked down for asking this on Server Fault.  So my question is this:  Is hardware related inquiries strictly prohibited from Server Fault and strictly related to Super User?

I am struggling a little to differentiate doe to the comments I got for the following question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/60549/has-my-graphics-card-blown
(now deleted, re-asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/32477/has-my-graphics-card-blown))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is definitely more SU then SF. SF is anything related to a System Administrator in a corporate environment. It is a very thin line but I would also move the question. SU handles more generic desktop queries for power users, where as the target audience of SF is more corporate system administrators.

Answer (score 2):

Server fault is for asking system administration questions about a system of desktops or servers that you administer. Not for asking a hardware question about one desktop where you happen to be an administrator. That is where I would draw the line at least.

Answer (score 1):

From the Server Fault /faq:

> Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. If you are in charge of ...
>
> - servers
> - networks
> - many desktop PCs (**other than your own**)
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question! Well, as long as the question is about your servers, your networks, or desktops you support, anyway.

I have no idea how you could have concluded that your question was appropriate for SF.

It's perfect for SU, though. Sounds like you found your way, which is the important thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are 199 questions tagged "hardware of SF right now. The first few in the newest view include questions about servers (boxes), gateways (boxes again), load balancers, domain controllers, hardware bang-for-the-buck optimization, power supplies, and so on.

The common denominator is "I run this pile of hardware for enterprise X, and I need to know..." which is what ServerFault is all about.

If you want to know about the relative merits of high density rack configuration, ServerFault is the place to ask. If you want to know what computer to get your college bound kid, go to SuperUser. Finding the exact line in between is a job for the high rep users on the two sites.